# How to convert a case-class-based RDD into a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

The [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection) shows how to create a DataFrame from an RDD, using Scala case classes to infer a schema. I am trying to reproduce this concept using `sqlContext.createDataFrame(RDD, CaseClass)`, but my DataFrame ends up empty. Here's my Scala code:

```
// sc is the SparkContext, while sqlContext is the SQLContext.

// Define the case class and raw data
case class Dog(name: String)
val data = Array(
    Dog("Rex"),
    Dog("Fido")
)

// Create an RDD from the raw data
val dogRDD = sc.parallelize(data)

// Print the RDD for debugging (this works, shows 2 dogs)
dogRDD.collect().foreach(println)

// Create a DataFrame from the RDD
val dogDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dogRDD, classOf[Dog])

// Print the DataFrame for debugging (this fails, shows 0 dogs)
dogDF.show()
```

The output I'm seeing is:

```
Dog(Rex)
Dog(Fido)
++
||
++
||
||
++
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you need is just

```
val dogDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dogRDD)
```

Second parameter is part of Java API and expects you class follows java beans convention (getters/setters). Your case class doesn't follow this convention, so no property is detected, that leads to empty DataFrame with no columns.

Comment: This worked. I also had to move the definition of the case class outside of my main function to avoid `error: No TypeTag available for Dog`. Thanks!

Comment: I see, very interesting, so the second parameter is only ever required when calling from the Java API, scala will just automagically detect the fields of the Type that should be converted to columns?

Comment: It worked only if `case class` moved outside of `main`. @Vitalii , @ sparkour .. is there any explanation for why `case class` need to be moved outside of `main`.

Comment: I am getting `abstract` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as field name as my case class has `abstract` as field name. Any workaround for this.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `DataFrame` directly from a `Seq` of case class instances using `toDF` as follows:

```
val dogDf = Seq(Dog("Rex"), Dog("Fido")).toDF
```

Comment: Remember to add import spark.implicits._

Answer (score 0):

Case Class Approach won't Work in cluster mode. It'll give `ClassNotFoundException` to the case class you defined.

Convert it a `RDD[Row]` and define the schema of your `RDD` with `StructField` and then `createDataFrame` like

```
val rdd = data.map { attrs => Row(attrs(0),attrs(1)) }  

val rddStruct = new StructType(Array(StructField("id", StringType, nullable = true),StructField("pos", StringType, nullable = true)))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,rddStruct)
```

`toDF()` wont work either

Comment: any explanations , why it wont work in cluster mode?