# Working only when case class defined outside main method to create Dataset[case class] or Dataframe[case class]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

This is working.

```
object FilesToDFDS {
    case class Student(id: Int, name: String, dept:String)
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("local").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
        import ss.implicits._

        val path = "data.txt"
        val rdd = ss.sparkContext.textFile(path).map(x => x.split(" ")).map(x => Student(x(0).toInt,x(1),x(2)))
        val df = ss.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", " ").load(path).map(x => Student(x.getString(0).toInt ,x.getString(1),x.getString(2)))
        val ds = ss.read.textFile(path).map(x => x.split(" ")).map(x => Student(x(0).toInt,x(1),x(2)))

        val rddToDF = ss.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)

    }
}
```

But, if case class moved inside main, `df`, `ds` giving compilation error.

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

And `rddToDF`  giving this compilation error `No TypeTag available for Student`

In this questions [ques1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004352/how-to-convert-a-case-class-based-rdd-into-a-dataframe) , [ques2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339060/creating-dataset-based-on-different-case-classes) people answered to move `case class` outside `main`. And this idea worked. But, why it is working only when `case class` moved outside main method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362186/why-is-the-spark-implicits-import-not-helping-with-encoder-derivation-inside-a

Answer (score 0):

I believe if a case class is defined within another class, then it needs an instance of that class to work properly. In this case, if you put your `Student` class within the main, then you would need something like `FilesToDFDS.Student` to make it work.